# PHP preg_split result not correct

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am trying to learn regex in PHP and messing around with the preg_split function.

It doesn't appear to be correct though, or my understanding is completely wrong.

The test code i am using is:

```
$string = "test ing ";
var_dump(preg_split('/t/', $string));
```

I would expect to get an array like the following:

```
[0] => "es" [1] => " ing "
```

but the following is being returned:

```
[0] => "" [1] => "es" [2] => " ing "
```

Why is there an empty string at the start?

I understand that i can use the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag to filter this but it shouldnt be there to begin with.  Should it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't it? This is exactly how it works. The semantics of a `split` operation are that you have a string of this format:

```
value-delimiter-value-delimiter-value-...-delimiter-value
```

(Note that it is starting and ending with a value, not a delimiter.)

So if your string starts with a delimiter, it is absolutely valid to assume that there is an empty value before that delimiter (since the delimiter is supposed to **split** something into two). You wouldn't generally want to reject the empty string between two consecutive `t`s either, would you?

And this is exactly what `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` is for. You use it whenever you **do** want to get rid of those empty strings.

As a simple example why you would want the default behavior, just think of CSV files. You want to split a line at (for example) `;`. You usually also want to allow for empty values. Now if the value in your first column was empty (meaning the line will *start* with `;`, and you chopped that first empty string away completely, then suddenly all indices in the resulting array would correspond to different columns. This is why you want to keep those empty strings as well. In many cases you know how many delimiters there are, and hence how many values - and you want to be able to identify which value belongs at which position. Even if some of them are empty.

Comment: Ok, so this was where my understanding was flawed.  It splits and looks behind the split points.

Answer (score 0):

It's working 100% correct.  The first character is a 't', so it's splitting on that 't' first.  Before the first 't' there is nothing, so the array result start with an entry of empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of the `t` at the beginning of your string. If you don't use the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` option, `preg_split` will treat an empty string as a valid split.

Think of it this way: Everywhere `preg_split` sees a `t`, it chops the string into two chunks: the chunk before the `t`, and the chunk after it. Even if one of the chunks doesn't have anything in it, it still counts. That piece is just an empty string.

For some applications, this would be perfectly useful -- for example, say you wanted to replace each `t` with something, but the replacement was too complicated to just use `preg_replace`. The language wants you to be able to choose, so it keeps the empty split unless you explicitly tell it not to with `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`.